# Broadcastreceiver in fragment not working

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

i was trying the NotificationListener to get the coming notifications. Two days ago my class was an activity and everything works fine. The service started and the notification came up in my view with the title, icon and the description of it. Yesterday i implemented the new Navigation View, so, i changed the activity to fragment. After that the notification not showing up. The service starts but if i try to debug the Broadcastreceiver (that is inside the fragment) doesn't work. If i try to create some log inside it they not works. I suppose that the Broadcastreceiver not starts at this point! This is the Broadcastreceiver

```
     /**
     * Broadcast receiver notifications
     ***/
    private BroadcastReceiver onNotice= new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            final String pack = intent.getStringExtra("package");
            String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");
            String text = intent.getStringExtra("text");

            if(!pack.equals("") || !title.equals("") || !text.equals("")) {
                notificationLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                notificationTitle.setText(title);
                notificationDescription.setText(text);

                try {
                    icon = getActivity().getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(pack);
                } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                notificationImage.setImageDrawable(icon);


            } else {
                notificationLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

        }
    };
```

and in my onResume() method of the fragment i wrote this:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(onNotice, new IntentFilter("Msg"));
```

I don't know if the change of the class type is the reason of this issue but it's the only change i made.

Comment: Fragment is added in Activity or not?

Comment: The MainActivity now is which one has the Navigation Drawer in which of course calls the fragment to open it onClick in the menu item of the drawer. Is this what you mean?

Comment: ok then where u are calling sendBroadCast method?

Comment: actually i only register the receiver in onResume() method... have i to implement something else? can i keep the Broadcastreceiver inside the fragment?

Comment: you need to call sendBroadCast method to fire BroadCast

Comment: So the registerReceiver isn't enough? and where have i to call the sendBroadCast method? In onResume()? on in onActivityCreated of my Fragment?